# How to read from one database and write to other database in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I have a multi-region database (MongoDB) infrastructure with replication. I want to record data to master DB and read data from other DB (replication) in the same region with the application server.
How to implement it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config/connection.js`:

```
mongodb: {
  adapter   : 'sails-mongo',
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  },
  url: 'mongodb://0.0.0.1,0.0.0.2:27017/db-name?replicaSet=rs0',
  readPreference: 'secondary'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to solve the problem on the application level I would go with the MongoDB [Read Preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) configuration. This approach has at least two advantages:

- your code does not change
- the functionality relies on the optimized and tested MongoDB engine